# How can I get selected row values from a jTable and add that values to another jTable?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-7

I tried to create a `jTable` by adding a column of type `boolean`, to tick the wanted rows. And get them into another similar `jTable`.

I used `jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(int, int, int);` but can't put selected `String` values to the `value` parameter.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

> I used jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(int, int, int); but can't put selected String values to the value parameter.

Sure you can, the signature is `setValueAt(Object, int, int)`. The first parameter is `Object`, not "int" so you can put any Object into a TableModel.

If you are talking about adding new rows of data to the second table then you need to use the `addRow(...)` method of the `DefaultTableModel`of your table. That is, the DefaultTableModel will initially contain no data so you can't just use the setValueAt(...) method. Instead you need to add a new row of data for every row that is selected in the first table.

If you need more help than post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

*JTable* is very flexible and could add and delete any row you desire.

The number of columns that constitute a row may vary from table to another so *JTable* has a model object through which you can manipulate the rows of the table.

The `JTable` will have a `DefaultTableModel`. You can add rows to the model with your data.

If you get the column values of a selected row of a JTable for example:

`String obj1` for row1, `String obj2` for row2, `String obj3` for row3, ...ect

***OR IF YOU NEED BOOLEAN :***

`Boolean obj1` for row1, `Boolean obj2` for row2, `Boolean obj3` for row3, ...ect

Then you can make the following:

```
Object[] row = { obj1 , obj2 , obj3 };
```

You get the object model of the destination table as follows:

```
DefaultTableModel model = ( DefaultTableModel ) jTable1.getModel();
```

Then add the manually created row to it:

```
model.addRow( row );
```

And that's it!